# Hide SELECT results in Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Within a stored procedure, I have a logic check that will throw an error & break my procedure if a SELECT statement returns any results, like so:

```
-- set breakpoint if true:
    SELECT myid, COUNT(*) AS [Records]
    FROM #mytemptable
    GROUP BY myid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN;
        THROW 51000,'ERROR - this is wrong', 1
    END
```

This correctly breaks my report when [Records] > 1. When there are no results however, I need to suppress the output of this empty SELECT query (reason being, this procedure feeds several downstream procedures).

This procedure also returns several other SELECT results that I do not want to suppress. How can I hide only this one empty result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `IF` and `EXISTS`?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT myid, COUNT(*) AS [Records]
           FROM #mytemptable
           GROUP BY myid
           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
          )
BEGIN
    THROW 51000,'ERROR - this is wrong', 1
END;
```

`BEGIN` doesn't traditionally take a semicolon after it.

Comment: Perfect, this will do it. Don't even need the BEGIN/END as well.

Comment: @Alex . . . I think I always put the `BEGIN`/`END` around the `THEN` part of the `IF`.  I find it prevents errors if I ever modify the code.